# DNN Error for DotNetNuke in a farm environment

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke, nlb

I'm working on a ASP.NET project that uses DNN (DotNetNuke). The production environment is we have 2 IIS servers with the website deployed on both. The two webservers have a network load-balancer in front. Both servers share the same SQL server instance and a file server where the content files are hosted.

I have already tested both webservers separately and works fine. But once they are brought together in the farm with the network load-balancer we intermittently get a gray page with "DNN Error. Site Unavailable. Return to Site" page.Also, if I just have one webserver with NLB configured, it works fine too.

There isn't much in the logs. The web.config file has:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
   <remove statusCode="404"/>
   <remove statusCode="500"/>
   <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPage.aspx" responseeMode="ExecuteURL">
   <error statusCode="500" path="/ErrorPage.aspx" responseeMode="ExecuteURL">
</httpErrors>
```

Becasue of this there isn't much in the IIS logs. I can see IIS calling `GET` method to this ErrorPage.aspx for some `500` error.

When I check the DNN error logs there's nothing happening in either of those 2 servers at this same time.

Some think the problem is with the network load-balancer. But I feel like some error is happening at the `http` level probably due to some configuration in the DNN components. But I'm totally new to DNN framework. So any pointers on where I should start debugging is really appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: There's a multiple error being logged in the IIS that says

```
aspxerrorpath=/WebResource.axd
```

I don't know if this is relevant to the DNN error.

Answer (score 2):

The error "This site is currently Unavailable" usually occurs due to one of these reasons:

1. There are no more available SQL connections
2. The SQL user account is disabled/configured incorrectly
3. There is a mismatch between the cached data and the current data

Recycling the AppPool fixes this most of the time (unless the SQL user account is wrong), but not sure this applies to a webfarm.

Check out the [Web Farm Configuration Guide](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Portals/0/SiteFiles/OtherAssets/Web_Farm_Configuration_Guide_4_1.pdf). It may contain useful info on how to solve your problem.

> For the exact error message try
>   http://yourdomain.com/install/install.aspx?mode=none

Comment: I don't think the SQL has an error because the applications run fine when they are running by themselves. Also, if a connection to SQL failed I'd see an exception at the application level. The shared cache could be causing a problem. Is there a way I can test this? Thanks for the resource, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, don't know. I have no experience with farm hosting. I just hope you can find something useful in the Configuration Guide